# Elastic search that matches part of a keyword field and does not match exact match of keyword field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create an elastic watcher that will send out an adaptive card to teams when our team member are running on an outdated version of the software.  I would like these to match up per year, not everything mixed together.  Here is what I currently have

```
POST _watcher/watch/_execute
{
  "watch": {
    "trigger": {
      "schedule": {
        "interval": "1w"
      }
    },
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
          "indices": [
            "*revit-event*"
          ],
          "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
          "body": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must_not": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              { "wildcard": { "software.version": "Autodesk Revit 2020" } }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "software.version": "Autodesk Revit 2023 23.1.10.4"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "software.version": "Autodesk Revit 2022 22.1.30.34"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "software.version": "Autodesk Revit 2021 21.1.70.21"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "software.version": "Autodesk Revit 2020 20220517_1515(x64)"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "computer.name"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "software.version"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "@timestamp": {
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
                        "gte": "now-1w",
                        "lt": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

I want everything that is in the software.version that matches Autodesk Revit 2020, but do not want to show the latest (correct version).  This will provide our IT team a list of people that need to get Revit 2020 updated to the correct year.  I have the other Years that we use shown to keep that part of the code the same.  when I create the watcher for Autodesk Revit 2022 I would only have to change the one spot.

I have tried match query and it did not work

```
"rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
          "body": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must_not": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              { "match": { 
                                "software.version":{
                                  "query": "2022",
                                  "operator": "and"
                                } }},
                               { "match": { 
                                "software.version":{
                                  "query": "Revit",
                                  "operator": "and"
                                } }}
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "software.version": "Autodesk Revit 2023 23.1.10.4"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
```

I tried the match_phrase_prefix but there is something about text and keywords not working the same.

My notification is still showing the Other years of Revit that do not match the full software version field.  So I am still seeing 2023 when I only want to see 2022.

I have the notifications and everything working great.  The filters are just causing me problems.  Any Ideas of what I should do?